# Pickling a Classifier in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, classification, google-earth-engine, random-forest

I'm busy trying to create a widely applicable reedbed vegetation classifier that could potentially classify any given area within Europe. I already have training data for an area around the Balaton lake in Hungary and the classification is very accurate >99%.

The problem is that the random forest classifier uses a lot of data and time while training. I know that within python there is a way to store a classifier using a "pickling" method, so if you would choose a different area you would not have to retrain your classifier every time. I was wondering if there is any way to do this in JavaScript within the Google Earth Engine?

Comment: I'd love to know if you managed to resolve this.  There's a pickle.js implementation apparently [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pickle-js/).  I'm in a similar situation...

Comment: In the end I did not use Pickle, just retrained the classifier each time. But thank you for pointing me on the pickle.js! I will try if this works soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the same classifier to a different set of images as long as the have the same bands as your original location. You still need to collect samples to test the model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using ee.Serializer(), you can serialize an earth engine object, also true for ee.Classifier().

```
var classifier_serialized = ee.Serializer.toJSON(classifier)
Export.table.toAsset(ee.FeatureCollection(empty_feature.set('classifier',json)),desc,AssetName)

    
// Load using this
var json = ee.String(ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection(assetName).first()).get('classifier'))
var classifier = ee.Deserializer.fromJSON(json)
```